# Can’t drive MOSFETs using SPWM technique

Tags: mosfet, stm32, mosfet-driver

I am trying to get 220-230 V sine wave. I am using SPWM technique to get the sine wave.

These are the codes which I am using to achieve my purpose.

```
#include "main.h"
const uint16_t dizi[201]={100,103,106,109,112,115,119,122,125,128,
                         131,134,136,139,142,145,148,150,153,
                         156,158,161,163,165,168,170,172,
                         174,176,178,180,182,184,185,187,188,
                         190,191,192,193,194,195,196,197,197,
                         198,198,199,199,199,199,199,199,199,
                         198,198,197,197,196,195,194,193,192,
                         191,190,188,187,185,184,182,180,178,
                         176,174,172,170,168,165,163,161,158,
                         156,153,150,148,145,142,139,136,134,
                         131,128,125,122,119,115,112,109,106,
                         103,100,97,94,91,88,85,81,78,
                         75,72,69,66,64,61,58,55,52,
                         50,47,44,42,39,37,35,32,30,
                         28,26,24,22,20,18,16,15,13,
                         12,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,
                         3,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,
                         1,2,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,
                         8,9,10,12,13,15,16,18,20,
                         22,24,26,28,30,32,35,37,39,
                         42,44,47,50,52,55,58,61,64,
                         66,69,72,75,78,81,85,88,91,
                         94,97,100};


const uint16_t dizi2[201]={100,97,94,91,88,85,81,78,75,
                      72,69,66,64,61,58,55,52,50,
                      47,44,42,39,37,35,32,30,28,
                      26,24,22,20,18,16,15,13,12,
                      10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,3,
                      2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
                      2,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,
                      9,10,12,13,15,16,18,20,22,
                      24,26,28,30,32,35,37,39,42,
                      44,47,50,52,55,58,61,64,66,
                      69,72,75,78,81,85,88,91,94,
                      97,100,103,106,109,112,115,119,122,
                      125,128,131,134,136,139,142,145,148,
                      150,153,156,158,161,163,165,168,170,
                      172,174,176,178,180,182,184,185,187,
                      188,190,191,192,193,194,195,196,197,
                      197,198,198,199,199,199,199,199,199,
                      199,198,198,197,197,196,195,194,193,
                      192,191,190,188,187,185,184,182,180,
                      178,176,174,172,170,168,165,163,161,
                      158,156,153,150,148,145,142,139,136,
                      134,131,128,125,122,119,115,112,109,
                      106,103,100};

TIM_HandleTypeDef htim1;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_tim1_ch1;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_tim1_ch2;

void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_DMA_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM1_Init(void);

int main(void)
{


HAL_Init();
SystemClock_Config();


MX_GPIO_Init();
MX_DMA_Init();
MX_TIM1_Init();

HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
HAL_TIMEx_PWMN_Start(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_1);

HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_2);
HAL_TIMEx_PWMN_Start(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_2);


HAL_TIM_PWM_Start_DMA(&htim1,TIM_CHANNEL_1,(uint32_t*)dizi,201);
HAL_Delay(1000);
HAL_TIM_PWM_Start_DMA(&htim1,TIM_CHANNEL_2,(uint32_t*)dizi2,201);
while (1)
  {
}
}
```

In my schematic I use STM32F407VC, IR2113, IRF630N and a transformer.

[image]

I found this schematic from IR2113 datasheet. It is a typical connection from datasheet. Voltage supply is 15 V. Transformer Np/Ns ratio is 0.1. Oscilloscope does not give me any outputs. Oscilloscope works 2-3 seconds and give me these errors:

```
[SPICE] DELMIN increased to 2.77556e-017 due to lack of time precision
[SPICE] transient GMIN stepping at time=0.201158
[SPICE] TRAN:  Timestep too small; timestep = 3.46945e-018: trouble with node #v:q4:fi2#branch.
```

I am having a trouble to find the mistake. Where am i doing wrong?

Comment: check X1: L, R values are realistic

Comment: your circuit doesn't seem right. You need to use a center tapped transformer on the primary. (That won't make the error messages go though)

Comment: Your current circuit makes no sense. Switching the top and bottom is next to useless - only 1 mosfet would be required but it would be a flyback converter.
You need a centre tapped transformer and two low side mosfets or half bridge and a capacitor or a full H bridge.

Comment: There are mistakes. You would have to have 4 switch H-Bridge or center tapped transformer. So your schematics is wrng.

Comment: Spice isn't good at simulating transients, sometimes even a switch creates issues so good luck with that.

Comment: @Kartman Thank you for helping me out. I am trying this schematic with center tapped transformer now. Should i connect center leg with 15 V voltage supply ?

Comment: @Kirambor, yes, the centre tap goes to 15V

Comment: Centre tap to +15V and both FETs are low side switches : like the classic (vacuum tube!) Class B amplifier.

Comment: @Kartman Sorry for late feedback. Can you please explain me why should i use two low side mosfets ?

Comment: Research the push-pull converter. That should tell you what you need to know.